# divs side by side issue

Tags: css, html

I have the following DIVs side by side.  I would like to hide right DIV and align the left DIV to center by default. Clicking on left DIV links shows the Right DIV. It seems to be working but I moved the code to a different machine. The left DIV doesn't move to left when the link clicked. So there a overlap. I am using IE 8 on both machines. Could you please let me know what could be wrong. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
#div_main {
    text-align: center;
}

#div_left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left; 
}

#div_right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

    <div id="div_main">
        <div id="div_right">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlGraph" runat="server" Style="display: none">
             </asp:panel>
        </div>
        <div id="div_left" >
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: The first wrong is to use IE8 if you ask me. But maybe you're stuck using win XP ? In that case, OS is the problem...

Comment: So... same page, same browser, same version, different machines? Caching problems.

Comment: I am having issue with Windows server 2008 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code at the top -

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
}
```

Reason -

I think the use of percentages is causing this issue. One of the `div`s has margin settings (some browsers assign default margins/padding to various elements on the page) which might be affecting the layout.

Comment: You know you could just use *

Comment: No! Older versions of IE are not happy with that :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the `display: none` to the CSS. The rest is a just a jQuery solution, moving the first with `float: left` and showing the right one

```css
#div_right {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$('#div_left').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('float', 'left');
    $('#div_right').show();
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q99f/)